# SSH tunnel to use RMySQL with RStudio

Tags: mysql, r, ssh, rstudio, rmysql

I’m newbie to R with RStudio using Mac(OS X).

I successfully use sequel Pro to see DB with like this.

[image]

I  use dbConnect with RMySQL and DBI(below code) with RStudio.

```
library(DBI)
library(RMySQL)
con <-  dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), 
              username = "username",
              password = "password",
              host = "hostname-xxx.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
              port = 3306, 
              dbname = "dbname"
)
```

but I've got below error.

```
Error in .local(drv, ...)
  Failed to connect to database: Error: Access denied for user 'username'@'yyyyyyyyyyymarunouchi.tokyo.ocn.ne.jp' (using password: YES)
```

So ssh tunnel like this using terminal.

```
ssh -f sshuser@xx.xxx.xx.xx -i ~/.ssh/ssh_key -L 3306:hostname-xxx.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 -N
```

and successfully logined.

after that, in order to confirm, executed below command(in terminal) but  failed after entering correct password.

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -p -u username dbname
```

with error code

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' to database 'dbname'
```

(other machine with same username successfully login. I didn't know why...)

and dbConnect(RMySQL with RStudio) is showing same above error.

Anyone same situation? Please tell me what to do.

Thank you.

Comment: This is just a matter of database credentials. You need to set up a user in your DBMS who has permission to access the DB that you login to and then use that account + password to login. This may not be the same as the account that you use to login to the server. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

This is just a matter of database credentials. You need to set up a user in your DBMS who has permission to access the DB that you login to and then use that account + password to login. This may not be the same as the account that you use to login to the server.

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

If this gives you any trouble then instead of granting `ALL PRIVILEGES` grant each permission one at a time. This is rare but it happens, especially with other DB's like Hive.

Comment: If it is database credential matter,  the "username" account settings for DB should be wrong, so wouldn't the ’mysql -h 127.0...’ command execute successfully for all of the terminals, or fail on all of them?

```Other machine with same username successfully login. I didn't know why..```

Comment: ` sql -h 127.0.0.1 -p password -u username dbname `  disappear above error and mysql command execute successfully in terminal. But dbConnect in RStudio occurs error:`  Error in .local(drv, ...): 
  Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'hostname-xxx.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (60) `